# Filtering For duplicate entries in ICollectionView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a class as

```
Class ABC()
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Category{get;set;}
}
```

List formed by this class is having value as :-

```
 Name = "A", Category = "Alphabet"
 Name = "1", Category = "Numeric"
 Name = "2", Category = "Numeric"
 Name = "B", Category = "Alphabet"
 Name = "A", Category = "Alphabet"
```

I've applied filter(using  ICollectionView) on above list based on category only as "Alphabets" and resulting list is:-

```
 Name = "A", Category = "Alphabet"
 Name = "B", Category = "Alphabet"
 Name = "A", Category = "Alphabet"
```

which is working fine but I am not able to filter out this duplicate entry from the list.
I am using WPF MVVM.
Please help.

Comment: Can you show how you are filtering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the filter callback return true only if the current object has the needed category AND is the first one with its name.

Something like this:

```
    ...
    ObservableCollection<ABC> Items { get;set}
    ListCollectionView ItemsView { get;set }
    ...
    // View filter logic
    ItemsView.Filter = o =>
            {
                var abc = o as ABC;
                if (abc == null) return false;
                return abc.Category == "Alphabet" &&
                       abc == Items.First(i => i.Name == abc.Name);
            };
```